# No puedo solucionar este problema de React-Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs

lo que pasa es que yo instalé **React-Router-dom v5** con **NPM** y me sale este siguiente error cuando quiero utilizar las etiquetas "" yo ya lo importé correctamente como dice la guía de **NPM** es decir hacerlo así -> **import { Router, Route } from 'react-router';** ahí ya esta bien creo yo, pero me sale este error cuando quiero compilar con npm start el proyecto que estoy realizando, que es el siguiente:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined

new Router

/mnt/c/Users/sirja/modules/Router.js:20

super(props);
  18 | 
  19 | this.state = {
> 20 |   location: props.history.location
  21 | };
```

**//This is a bit of a hack. We have to start listening for location changes here in the constructor in
//case there are any s on the initial render. If there are, they will replace/push when they //mount and since cDM fires in children before parents, we may get a new location before the  is //mounted.**

me sale todo ese error y no entiendo el porqué, podrían ayudarme a solucionarlo por favor, se los agradecería mucho ??

Comment: perdón las etiquetas que quiero utilizar son estas <Router><Router/>

Comment: Instalaste React-router o React-router-dom ??

Comment: hola Enzo instale React-router-dom y me sale ese error y no se porqué, podrías ayudarme a solucionarlo por favor ??

Comment: Puedes mostrar cono estas inicializando y usando `<Router>` y `<Route>`, puede que estes pasando propiedades de manera incorrecta.

Comment: mira la documentación https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start

Comment: lo habia hecho de esta manera pero no me habia funcionado  <Router>
    <Switch>
       <Route path="/path1" component={ App }/>
       <Route path="/path2" component={ App2 }/>
    </Switch>
  </Router>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes asegurarte de importar los componentes de react-router-dom de la manera correcta

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Y luego usar Router de una de estas dos maneras:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Route path="/" component={ App }/>
  </BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Para una sola ruta, o usando Switch

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
       <Route path="/" component={ App }/>
       <Route path="/path2" component={ App2 }/>
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Sin olvidar incluir el componente Switch de react-router

```
import { Switch, Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
```

Comment: hola gracias por tu aporte ya me funcionó el problema era que lo importe mal y por eso me salió ese error, por ejemplo en ves de escribir "from react-router-dom" lo había escrito anteriormente como "from react-router" y no lo complete, entonces hice eso y me funcionó muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

para que no tengan ese error en **react-router-dom**, primero tienen que saber que están instalando con **NPM**, recuerden que hay tres dependencias de REACT-ROUTER y son muy diferentes estas son:

**react-router-dom** para navegadores, también **react-router-native** para aplicaciones móviles y únicamente **react-router** que es el principal y te instala todo de manera directa, en este caso yo quiero instalar **react-router para navegadores** lo instalaremos de la siguiente manera:

```
$ npm install --save react-router-dom
```

en el **package-json** que es donde se instala y donde dice **dependicies** encontraran la ultima versión de react-router-dom, en este caso a mi me instaló la versión **5.2.0** aveces les puede salir una versión anterior así que les recomiendo que ejecuten este comando en la terminal de **Ubuntu** para que tengan la versión actualizada por ejemplo

```
$npm install --save react-router-dom@5.2.0
```

tal y como lo ves escrito lo puedes hacer y si quieres una versión anterior también lo puedes hacer, entonces revisa el documento de react-router para que encuentres la versión que deseas instalar

hasta ahí es la **instalación correcta** que siempre deben ustedes hacer...

ahora si vamos al grano para corregir ese **error** que me sucedió.

Por favor siempre importen **REACT-ROUTER** de esta manera para que no tengan problemas en el código

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
```

Importándolo de esa manera podremos usar las **dos etiquetas** para dividir nuestras aplicaciones o componentes en rutas que es lo que necesitamos y para eso podemos utilizar cualquiera de las dos etiquetas

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Route exact path= "/ruta1" component= {MiPagina} />
</BrowserRouter>
```

o también puedes usar la etiqueta **Router** en caso de que no quieras usar **BrowserRouter** y lo puedes hacer así:

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path= "/ruta1" component= {MiPagina} />
      <Route exact path= "/ruta2" component= {MisitioWeb} />
      <Route exact path= "/ruta3" component= {MiPagina2} />
      <Route exact path= "/ruta4" component= {MisitioWeb2} />
    </Switch>
 </Router>
```

bien ahora ustedes se preguntarán ¿porqué respondes a tu misma pregunta si ya sabes la respuesta? y créanme que no falta la gente que es así, entonces mi respuesta es la siguiente:

**R/** porqué no sabia como hacerlo, como instalarlo de manera correcta y también no sabia porqué me sucedió ese error y si te estoy enseñando todo esto es porque investigué y quiero que se te haga mas fácil para que no tengas errores, es solamente un aporte para muchos que no sepan que hacer, espero les guste este aporte y califiquen si este aporte es útil, gracias y nunca paremos de aprender